# How to jump from one TextField to another with keyboard Action in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, textformfield

I have two Rows with a two TextFormField Widgets in each Row like a Table. Now I want that when the user clicks next in the keyboard, he jumps to the TextFormField on the right, so that he stays in the same Row. But with my Code he jumps to the TextFormField below.
How can I change it so that the user jumps to the TextFormField in the same Row?

```
Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: TextFormField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: TextFormField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Row(children: [
        Container(
          width: 50,
          child: TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          width: 50,
          child: TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          ),
        ),
      ])
    ]));
```

Comment: Look at `FocusNode` => https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus